# Kotlin: Differences between channel.close() and channel.cancel()

Tags: android, kotlin

So I was going through the documentation of Kotlin channels and found these two methods.

[close()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/close.html)

[cancel()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-receive-channel/cancel.html)

These are the differences I have understood

| close() | cancel() |
| --- | --- |
| Immediately stops the channel from sending, but not receiving (if buffer is present) | Immediately stops the channel for both sending and receiving() |
| Does not clear buffer | Clears buffer |
| isClosedForSend = true; isClosedForReceive = false (if buffer is present) | isClosedForSend = true; isClosedForReceive = true |

Is there any other practical difference between the two?

If I want something that immediately stops all transactions on the channel, I should use `cancel()` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct - use `cancel()` to immediately prevent sending, and stop any receivers.

Also: `cancel()` also accepts an optional `cause` parameter that allows you to provide a reason for the cancellation, and it propagates at the consumers. This can be useful for all kinds of situations, such has qualifying the exact reason for cancellation, communicating retry/backoff behavior, etc.